# How can I use history.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js, html5-history

I want to store history of buttons clicked so it will be easy if someone press back button it goes to the previous state. I got to know about history.js and I researched about it https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ but I am not getting the things, that how I actually implement this to my scenario.

JS files I am using:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.history.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="start-button">
<img src="img/start-button.png" id="start-button">
</div>
<div class="home-menu">
<ul>
<li id="first"><span>first</span></li>
<li id="second"><span>second</span></li>
<li id="third"><span>third</span></li>
<li id="fourth"><span>fourth</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div class="text">
some dummy text
</div>
<div class="back-btn">
<img src="img/back-btn.png" id="back-btn">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#start-button").click(function(e){
$('.start-button').css("display", "none");
$('.home-menu').show();
});
$("#first").click(function(e){
$('.main').show();
$('.home-menu').hide();
});
});
```